# How to prove these two derangement number formulas are equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

In helping someone with a [coding challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/9cvo0f/20180904_challenge_367_easy_subfactorials_another/) for calculating the derangement number, I learned that the formula I came up with:

$$d(n)=n\cdot d(n-1)+(-1)^n$$

is not the one that most references quote: both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) list:

$$d(n)=(n-1)[(d(n-1)+d(n-2)]$$

instead. I can see how the second formulation is easier to arrive at intuitively, but I can't think how these two can be *proven* to be the same. Wolfram lists both, and indeed the series of $d(n)$ are identical empirically, but how would one go about proving they are the same?

Comment: Wolfram lists both recursions with just the word “and” between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first formula can easily be used to derive the second formula ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
d_{n-1}&=&(n-1)d_{n-2}+(-1)^{n-1} \\
d_{n}&=&nd_{n-1}+(-1)^{n} \\
&=&(n-1)d_{n-1}+d_{n-1}+(-1)^{n} \\
&=&(n-1)d_{n-1}+(n-1)d_{n-2}+\underbrace{(-1)^{n-1}+(-1)^{n}}_{=0}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you!  Too me a minute to figure out what you did from line 2 to 3, but get it now! $nd_{n-1} = (n-1)d_{n-1} + d_{n-1}$